# uninitialized constant AlwaysVerifySSLCertificates (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Was following the following link: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-cure-nethttps-risky-default-https-behavior-4010.html

Trying to execute the following snippet:

```
    require 'always_verify_ssl_certificates'

    AlwaysVerifySSLCertificates.ca_file = "C:/certs/cacert.pem"

    puts "test 1"
    http= Net::HTTP.new('https://some.ssl.site', 443)
    http.use_ssl = true
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/')
    response = http.request(req)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
api_basics.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant AlwaysVerifySSLCertificates (NameError)
```

Already installed the always_verify_ssl_certificates gem.

```
gem install always_verify_ssl_certificates
Fetching: always_verify_ssl_certificates-0.3.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed always_verify_ssl_certificates-0.3.0
Parsing documentation for always_verify_ssl_certificates-0.3.0
Installing ri documentation for always_verify_ssl_certificates-0.3.0
Done installing documentation for always_verify_ssl_certificates after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

So not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, always_verify_ssl_certificates gem has no such constant defined.
Try to rewrite as following:

```
require 'always_verify_ssl_certificates'
...

http= Net::HTTP.new('https://some.ssl.site', 443)
http.ca_file = "C:/certs/cacert.pem"

...
```